# NLP API for part of speech tagging

Tags: api, nlp

I want to use a REST API to perform part of speech (POS) tagging.  I don't want to host and maintain the models myself.  I tried doing this but it is costly, and many of the APIs (e.g. Stanford Parser) are actually pretty slow.  Am open to running libraries locally if there is a fast one.

What alternatives/approaches do people recommend using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much looking around, I ended up using this API because it's free (up to 50K calls/mo) and works well in C#:

https://www.cloudmersive.com/

Comment: As of today I see 2 caveats:
1. The API docs are out of date (ex. some method names changed). I only checked javascript.
2. The [POS tagger](https://api.cloudmersive.com/docs/nlp.asp#tag-PosTagger) endpoint only supports English.

Here's a sandbox example: [gist.github.com/ogallagher/5be9](https://gist.github.com/ogallagher/5be9bfe5c1ef757cf4faccaac3dc7a55)

Answer (score 2):

Try using spacy.

https://spacy.io/

It is much faster and easier to use than other frameworks in the market.